# Running MySQL on Amazon EC2 with EBS

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, volume, amazon-ebs

I have a production server whose MYSQL may not be backed up.  The instance in question has an EBS backed root device (/dev/sda1), which is persistently storing files.  It's not clear to me whether it is naturally storing my MYSQL data and binary log files persistently.

Should it do so if it's mounted at root? I would think so.

Should I instead attach and mount another volume and then point the MYSQL server at the new location?

My commands look like the following (plus locking the MYSQL table while creating the snapshot)

```
    sudo mkdir /vol/etc /vol/lib /vol/log
    sudo mv /etc/mysql     /vol/etc/
    sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /vol/lib/
    sudo mv /var/log/mysql /vol/log/

    sudo mkdir /etc/mysql
    sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql
    sudo mkdir /var/log/mysql

    echo "/vol/etc/mysql /etc/mysql     none bind" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
    sudo mount /etc/mysql

    echo "/vol/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql none bind" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
    sudo mount /var/lib/mysql

    echo "/vol/log/mysql /var/log/mysql none bind" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
    sudo mount /var/log/mysql
```

I am no sys admin expert and I don't want to screw up my existing database.  Is there any risk here?  Should I even bother with an additional device here or just stick with the built in root device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I moved the /etc/mysql and /var/lib/mysql directories to my EBS and created symlinks in their previous locations.

That way I didn't have to modify configuration files or worry about something not finding the files.

The reason I also moved /etc/mysql was so that the configuration files and maintenance script would not be lost if I attached the EBS to another instance.

As for a backup of that data, it would be best to create another instance and create a master/master configuration so you also get the benefits of failover.

Comment: Hi Kayak.  What does a master/master config mean exactly?  Any resources that you'd recommend that I can start to learn about it?

Comment: With the standard Master/Slave replication, the slave can fall behind and not be current. This generally isn't an issue until the Master fails. At that point you have to determine where the slave is in the replication process and then get it current before you can bring it online as the Master. With a Master/Master configuration, the 2 servers are always equal thus making for a complete backup and failover solution. Here is a guide for setting it up to give you a bit better of an idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about data persistence:

Take a snapshot of /dev/sda1, create a completely separate instance (t1.micro works great for this), create a new volume based off the snapshot you took of /dev/sda1, then mount that new volume on the new separate instance?  If your data is present on the new volume, it's definitely getting stored in EBS on /dev/sda1.

Having said that: a lot of the default Linux images are set up to automatically terminate the root (/dev/sda1) volume when the instance terminates.  Meaning: if you ever lose an instance, you're also losing all your data on the volume if you don't have it backed up elsewhere.  An easy way to keep backups is to just use the EC2 facilities to take a snapshot of the volume daily.  It's pretty easy to create a script that takes a snapshot and removes old daily periodic snapshots once the new snapshot is complete.  If you're looking for smaller backup sizes or incremental backup strategies, you can write more advanced scripts that fire up a t1.micro in an alternate availability zone or region, perform the backup on just the MySQL data via whatever mechanism you like, then shuts the t1.micro instance back down.

Comment: Great answer. As a bonus, you're testing your disaster recovery procedures each time.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Thanks!  I've battle-tested that process the hard way a couple of times already...

Comment: Hi Bob, great answer.  I guess my source of confusion was that I did try what you propose here (take a snapshot of sda1) and mount it on a new instance.  My problem was that some of the software that I downloaded onto my original instance (namely MYSQL, APACHE, etc) did not transfer with the volume. I didn't understand that since the volume was mount at /

Comment: Also, the Ubuntu Lucid AMI that I am using comes with an attached EBS device at root by default (as I've said before) should I detach it and manually attach the snapshotted volume at root?

Comment: @Brendan: I generally leave my EBS root volumes alone then follow a procedure similar to what KayamJim writes, below - basically mount an additional EBS volume where my database tablespaces normally go, that way when I take a snapshot I just get the database tablespaces instead of the whole root volume (which can easily be re-created from an AMI.)

Comment: Definitely Bob, that was going to be my plan. The code that I posted above is intended to do just that.  I just wanted to make sure I dont #!^$ things up by moving /etc/mysql.  I'm overly paranoid about everything server related :)

Answer (score 2):

If you stop your instance it will be similar to regular shutdown and EBS volume should remain with all data.
If you terminate instance than, I think, all data since snapshot will be gone.

But normally I don't see much reason to terminate it. In any case, it should simple to try out
on a test instance. You could just write some files and see what happens under different use cases.

This way you would also feel much safer than just relying on someone's answer.

Comment: Do note that you can turn termination protection on for an instance to avoid "whoopsies!" :-)